# Create Ubuntu Server resource on Azure with Terraform.io

Tags: azure, ubuntu-16.04, terraform

I really like Terraform.io and I'd like to adopt it for my new project.

I am trying to deploy a Ubuntu Server on my Azure subscription using Terraform.

I have created an example.tf file with this content:

```
# Configure Azure provider
provider "azure" {
  publish_settings = "${file("credentials.publishsettings")}"
}

# Create web server
resource "azure_instance" "web" {
  image = "Ubuntu Server 16.04 LTS"
  location = "ukwest"
  name = "some_name"
  size = "A0"
  username = "some_user"
}
```

When I run

```
terraform apply
```

I get this error:

```
* azure_instance.web: When using a platform image, the 'storage' parameter is required
```

So I tried to add an storage parameter in the resource element, like this:

```
# Create web server
resource "azure_instance" "web" {
  image = "Ubuntu Server 16.04 LTS"
  storage = "abc"
  location = "ukwest"
  name = "cloudlabs"
  size = "A0"
  username = "cloudlabs"
}
```

But then I get this other error message:

```
* azure_instance.web: : invalid or unknown key: storage
```

... And I'm stuck in here. I'm probably doing something wrong that is very obvious since this is my first tf file. Any ideas welcome!

Comment: I'm not an Azure user, but as long as I see the document, it looks like `storage_service_name` instead of `storage`. https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azure/r/instance.html#storage_service_name

Comment: Ah, you are very right! I was not looking in the right place of the docs :) If you put it as an answer and not a comment I'll choose it as valid.

Comment: Ahh yes, this looks like a bug in that error message. Confirmed in the code that `storage_service_name` is the attribute it's looking for, in spite of the error message.

Comment: @zapatilla Yeah, I posted it as an answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not an Azure user, but as long as I see the document, it looks like `storage_service_name` instead of `storage`.

See: https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azure/r/instance.html#storage_service_name